# How to write a function for and for loop with embedded if else statement?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, if-statement

I have just started using R for a course I'm taking and it asked for integer values > 0 (argument1) and which will multiply values <25 and >75 by a set multiplier (argument 2) and the other elements by a different multiplier (argument 3).

I already have the previous h and s values:

```
h=sample(1:100,40)

s=c()
 for(i in 1:100){if(h[i]<25){s[i]<-h[i]*10}
else if(h[i]>75){s[i]<-h[i]*10}
else{s[i]<-h[i]*0.1}}
Error in if (h[i] < 25) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

The error message shows up in the above for loop but if I ignore it I still get the answer. I want but would not work in the function.

```
fun2<-function(x=s,arg1,arg2,arg3)
{w<-for(i in 1:100){if(h[i]>0){s[i]<-h[i]*arg1}else if(h[i]<25){s[i]<-
h[i]*arg2}
else if(h[i]>75){s[i]<-h[i]*arg2}
else{s[i]<-h[i]*arg3}}
return(w)}

fun2(arg1=10,arg2=3,arg3=10)
Error in if (h[i] > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I am unsure where to put the true/false statement in the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `length(h)`.

You'll see that you are trying to loop over 100 indexes while having only 40 elements. If you replace your first line by `h = sample(1:100,100)`, your first code should work.

As for your second attempt, you cannot assign a for-loop to a variable. Store your variable `w` before looping and the assign the new values that you are calculating, like this.

```
fun2<-function(x=s,arg1,arg2,arg3){
  w<-s
  for(i in 1:100){
   if(h[i]>0){
    w[i]<-h[i]*arg1
   }
   ... # some if statement
 return(w)
}
```

As a side note, your function won't give you the results you are looking for because your first `if` condition discards the following `else if`. I would remove the first if block and replace the next one by `if(h[i] < 25 & h[i]> 0)`.